# "pull" process/job into the background

Tags: linux, process

I know of terminating a command with & and then moving it into the background by pressing Ctrl-Z and then bg [pid], and I also know of nohup.

But say you started a process that turned out to take much longer than one expected, is there a way of pulling, so to speak, this process from another terminal screen into the background so that even if I log off from the server the process would continue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Suspend it:

  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>
- restart in background:

  ```
  bg
  ```
- and tell the shell to not kill it on logout (SIGHUP):

  ```
  disown
  ```

  Note: Plain `disown` removes the job from the shell's `jobs` list completely, while `disown -h` just marks it as "do not kill on logout" but leaves on the list.

Comment: You can do this mid-process?  Take this for an example.  I have a FreeNAS box and I mount the old Windows share, then I start copying from the old to the new only to find out that copying 1 TB over a 100Mb network is taking longer than I'd like.  Could I do what you just described AFTER starting the copy?

Comment: @Mustafa: Yes, that's precisely what I described. (You _do_ already know the meaning of `Ctrl-Z` and `bg`, don't you?)

Comment: Yeah, I didn't know about disown though. Many thanks :)

Comment: Another thing. Is there any way I can "re-own" a process? Or am I asking for too much?

Comment: @Mustafa: You cannot. (There are tools such as `retty`, but they don't work well.) Next time, run the program inside `tmux`/`screen`/`dtach`, but for now you'll have to live with it.

Answer (score 1):

Always run "screen" when you first login. Look into https://launchpad.net/byobu
I use byobu to automatically start a screen session whenever I log in. That way, I automatically have screen running and I can disconnect the session or start a new window whenever I need it.

Comment: Nice! I sorta knew that there should be something like that. Good to know I'm not the first one in the world to encounter something like this :p  But nothing that would do what I said?  I'm backing up VMs and the smarty that I am didn't realize that they're in excess of 1 TB :s

Comment: I don't know of a way to do exactly what you ask.